# Como bloquear usuários baseado em sua localização?

Tags: php, javascript, ip, proxy

Tenho uma aplicação onde usuários tipo A posta informações. Por default esses posts estarão disponíveis para quaisquer usuário na web, em qualquer lugar do mundo.

Mas existe a possibilidade do usuário A restringir o seu post 123 para algumas cidades. Ou seja digamos que o usuárioA proibiu o seu post 123, de estar disponível para pessoas que acessam das cidades de Brasília, Salvador e André da Rocha (pequena cidade do Rio Grande do Sul). Estou usando exemplos aleatórios entre pequenas e médias cidades.

Como implementar tal funcionalidade?

Vamos considerar que todos usuários que irão acessar o sistema não estarão fazendo uso de proxy.

Estou usando php.

Answer (score 0):

No site do php eles fazem referência a extensão **GEOIP**.

Com ela você consegue informações detalhadas de um host name ou um Ip.

Veja na documentação [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.geoip.php).

**Ou** você pode utilizar dessa api aqui https://ipinfo.io/.

Podendo consultar antes de exibir os posts disponíveis para o usuário 
da cidade  em questão, e tomar a decisão de exibir ou não

**Ex**

```
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
  console.log(response.ip, response.country);
}, "jsonp")
```

Acho que isso atenderia a situação que precisa.

> Na comunidade so stack (inglês) já foi feito essa pergunta e tem uma
>   boa solução implementada lá, verifique [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409999/getting-the-location-from-an-ip-address?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).